# help to creating a formula on mysql to create another column on another table

Tags: mysql

just starting with mysql...
had this table **rating** with this placement...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kExbh.jpg

i want to get the average value of rating on a specific question_id(example: question_id=1, therefore: (5+4+3)/3=average and question_id=2, therefore:(3+4)/2=average) and transfer the value of average to another table which is **result**...that would look like below...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1erd.jpg

any help will be greatly appreciated...^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO results (subject_id, question_id, average)
SELECT subject_id, question_id, AVG(rating)
FROM rating
GROUP BY subject_id, question_id
```